# How can we ignore the apostrophe (') in like query of ormlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

My code is:-

```
QueryBuilder<PatientDetails, Integer> qb = patientDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().like("patientname", "%" + searchItem + "%");
patientsDetailsLit = patientDao.query(qb.prepare());
```

if searchItem  content apostrophe (') then code will crash.

Comment: That's one reason to use prepared statements. Doing it the way you are doing it also leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. However, I don't know the QueryBuilder class you are using, so I can't tell you how prepared statments are best created in your context.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [Select Arguments](http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg):

```
QueryBuilder<PatientDetails, Integer> qb = patientDao.queryBuilder();
SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
qb.where().like("patientname", selectArg);
selectArg.setValue("%" + searchItem + "%");
patientsDetailsLit = patientDao.query(qb.prepare());
```

Comment: Spot on.  The `SelectArg` class uses the SQL ? and argument feature and should also be used to protect against SQL injection attacks.